# GORM PostgreSQL getting date column without timezone

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I'm learning golang atm, and currently I'm using gorm trying to select query getting date column, but it keep returning '2020-01-10T00:00:00Z', how do I get rid of the timezone?

I've tried changing date to time.Time or string, nothing works, here is the code

```
type Price struct {
    DateStay time.Time `json:"date"`
    Price    int       `json:"price"`
}
```

Update: 
This is the code that I am using

```
        var price []models.Price
        err = models.DB.Raw(`
            SELECT P.date_stay, P.price
            FROM prices p
            WHERE P.room_type_id = ?
        `, roomTypeId).Scan(&price).Error
```

I tried to P.date_stay::date, date(P.date_stay) on the query but nothing works

I expect it to return '2020-01-10'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using time.Time as a type for the date is probably best.

You can format the result of the date by setting the format to the desired date format you want.
(dd-mm-yyyy or whatever order you please).

Then you can format the value using time.Parse(format, date)

```
format := "2000-01-13"
formattedDate, err := time.Parse(format, price.DateStay)
```

assuming price is a result from your select query.

If you time is a time.Time you can try using `price.DateStay.Format(format)`

Comment: thanks, this might help but my price variable is in array, while foreach-ing them using this code might work but I want it to automatically apply to the struct, is it possible?

Comment: You could make a custom data type where you parse the time to the date only.
Take a look at the gorm.io documentation for that (https://gorm.io/docs/data_types.html)
But I would suggest against it, it is probably better keeping the object as a date and formatting the date wherever you are actually using this value in your application (whether that be on the client's side, or in in a frontend application, or somewhere else in your code).

Comment: Sorry I voted solved without trying it, after trying it, I got error on price.Datestay (line 2 of your code answer) with error of "cannot use price.DateStay (variable of type time.Time) as string value in argument to time.Parse"
Update: I updated it the data type to string, but the timezone still stuck hmm maybe my query?

Comment: my bad I thought you had a string. You can parse a time object using time.Format(format)